# Fractal rendering fun time

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, graphics, fractals

I wrote up a script a while back to let me play around with fractals. The idea was to have direct access to the script that creates the fractal. None of that close, edit, then run hassle; just edit then run.

**renderscript.py** contains the GUI:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfile

class View(tk.Frame):
    count = 0
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Button(self, text="open", command=self.open).pack(fill=tk.X)
        tk.Button(self, text="save", command=self.save).pack(fill=tk.X)
        tk.Button(self, text="run program", command=self.draw).pack(fill=tk.X)
        self.txt = tk.Text(self, height=30)
        scr = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        scr.config(command=self.txt.yview)
        self.txt.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set)
        scr.pack(side="right", fill="y", expand=False)
        self.txt.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.pack()
    def draw(self, size=500):
        exec(str(self.txt.get(1.0, tk.END)))
        self.pixels = [[(0, 0, 0) for y in range(size)] for x in range(size)]
        self.pixels = render(self.pixels)
        window = tk.Toplevel(self)
        window.resizable(0,0)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=size, height=size, bg='white')
        canvas.pack()
        img = tk.PhotoImage(width=size, height=size)
        canvas.create_image((size/2, size/2), image=img, state="normal")
        for y in range(size):
            for x in range(size):
                img.put(self.rgbtohex(self.pixels[x][y]), (x,y))
        window.mainloop()
    def rgbtohex(self, rgb):
        return ("#" + "{:02X}" * 3).format(*rgb)
    def open(self):
        self.txt.delete(1.0, tk.END)
        self.txt.insert(tk.END, open(askopenfilename()).read())
    def save(self):
        f = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".py")
        if f is None:
            return
        text2save = str(self.txt.get(1.0, tk.END))
        f.write(text2save)
        f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.resizable(0,0)
    main = View(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: renderscript.py screenshot]

**fractal.py** contains example fractal routines:

```
class Fractal:
    def mandelbrot(self, x, y, scale, center=(2.2, 1.5)):
        n = lambda c: self.iterate_mandelbrot(c)
        return self.calcolor(x, y, scale, center, n)

    def julia(self, x, y, scale, center=(1.5, 1.5)):
        n = lambda c: self.iterate_mandelbrot(complex(0.3, 0.6), c)
        return self.calcolor(x, y, scale, center, n)

    def calcolor(self, x, y, scale, center, nf):
        c = complex(x * scale - center[0], y * scale - center[1])
        n = nf(c)
        if n is None:
            v = 1
        else:
            v = n/100.0
        return v

    def iterate_mandelbrot(self, c, z = 0):
        for n in range(256):
            z = z*z +c
            if abs(z) > 2.0:
                return n
        return None

    def griderator(self, w, h):
        for x in range(w):
            for y in range(h):
                yield x, y

    def render(self, pixels):
        scale = 1.0/(len(pixels[0])/3)
        for x, y in self.griderator(len(pixels), len(pixels[0])):
            i = self.mandelbrot(x, y, scale) * 256
            r, g, b = int(i % 16 * 16), int(i % 8 * 32), int(i % 4 * 63)
            pixels[x][y] = (r, g, b)
        return pixels

global render
render = Fractal().render
```

[image: fractal.py screenshot]
[image: alternate fractal.py screenshot]

The script does block while rendering the script. Try replacing `mandelbrot` with `julia`. I am looking for feedback on style and usability.

Comment: I'm just curious-- how long does it take you to render the Mandelbrot set?

Comment: @Myridium 8 seconds on my box

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. In `calcator`, I would use a ternary expression: `return 1. if n is None else n/100.`
2. `calcator` can be made even more efficient by having `iterate_mandelbrot` return `100.` if the loop finished.  Then you just divide the result of that by 100.  This will result in 1. if the loop exits, avoiding the `if` test entirely.
3. I would only do run `self.mandelbrot` in your loop, and store the result of that function to a 2D numpy array.  Then you can vectorize the rest of the calculation, since it is all just basic math.  This should substantially increase performance.  You can even move the `n/100` outside the for loop to further improve performance.
4. If the previous suggestion does not increase performance enough, you might be able use `multiprocessing.Pool.imap` to further increase the performance of the loop.
5. For an even more extreme vectorization, you can do all your calculations on all pixels at once.
6. Rather than having a `griditor` function, just use `itertools.product`.
7. Follow pep8
8. I would put the current contents of the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block in a `main` function and just call that function inside the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.
9. In `render` I would allow the code to pass a string (which defaults to `mandelbrot`, and use `getattr` to dynamically call method with that name.
10. I would rename `iterate_mandelbrot` to `iterate_pixel`.
11. I would put in `mandelbrot` an argument for `z` that lets the user change `z`.  Similarly, I would put an argument in `julia` that lets the user change `(0.3, 0.6)` to something else.
12. `render` should accept `*args, **kwargs` that are then passed directly to the `mandelbrot` or `julia` method.
13. I would move the `julia` and `mandelbrot` lambdas into their own methods.  Or better yet, I would refactor so you just pass the `c` and `z` argument.
14. In `render`, I would let the user set the scale with an argument.  The `scale` argument would default to `None`. If it is `None`, it would be computed automatically as is done now.
15. In `render`, you only ever work with integers.  So I would use `n//100` in `calcator` to make sure it returns an integer.  This allows you to avoid the later integer conversions.

So here is my version of `Fractal`

```
import numpy as np


class Fractal:        
    def mandelbrot(self, pixels, scale, center=(2.2, 1.5), z=0.):
        return self.calcolor(pixels, scale, center, zs=z)

    def julia(self, pixels, scale, center=(1.5, 1.5), c=(0.3, 0.6)):
        if not hasattr(c, 'imag'):
            c = complex(*c)
        return self.calcolor(pixels, scale, center, cs=c)

    def calcolor(self, pixels, scale, center, cs=None, zs=None):
        pixels = pixels.asarray(pixels)

        xpixels = np.arange(pixels.shape[0])[None, :]
        ypixels = np.arange(pixels.shape[1])[:, None]

        val = (xpixels+ypixels*1j)*scale-complex(*center)
        if cs is None and zs is None:
           raise ValueError('Either cs or zs must be specified')
        if cs is None:
           cs = val
        if zs is None:
           zs = val
        ns = np.full_like(val, 100, dtype='int16')

        for n in range(256):
            zs = zs**2 +cs
            ns[ns>0 & np.abs(zs)>2.0] = n
        return ns

    def calc_pixels(self, cs, zs):

    def render(self, pixels, scale=None, method='mandelbrot', *args, **kwargs):
        if scale is None:
            scale = 1.0/(len(pixels[0])/3)

        try:
            func = getattr(self, method)
        except AttributeError:
            raise ValueError('Unknown method %s' % method)
        i = func(pixels, scale, *args, **kwargs)*256

        r = i%16 * 16
        g = i*8 * 32
        b = i%4 * 63

        return np.dstack([r, g, b])
```